# If two continuous maps of an interval commute, then they agree at some point

Tags: real-analysis, fixed-point-theorems

Let $f,g:[0,1] \rightarrow [0,1]$ be continuous functions such that $f\circ g =g\circ f$. Prove that there exists $x \in [0,1]$ such that $f(x)=g(x)$

Comment: Do you mean $x \in [0,1]$? Also for the compositions to make sense, you'd need $f, g \colon [0,1] \to [0,1]$.

Comment: OP: Do you care about saying anything? My edit changed many critical parts of your problem (which should have been stated more clearly). Please let us know if this new problem is the one you're solving.

Comment: I think that if this is the case, then $f \circ g = g \circ f$ isn't needed anymore. I'm not too sure though.

Comment: @BolzWeir: It is still needed. For example, $f = 1/4$  and $g = 1/2$ meets everything else.

Comment: @PaulSinclair: doesn't $f \to [0,1]$ mean that $\operatorname{Range}(f) = [0,1]$?

Comment: No. It only means the codomain is $[0, 1]$. A function is not required to hit every point in its codomain.

Comment: What is the source of this problem?

Comment: See also: [Commuting functions on the closed interval have the same value somewhere](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/774855)

Answer (score 5):

This answer was inspired by the one of @PaulSinclair.

Let us assume that the claim is false, so that $f\left(x\right)\neq g\left(x\right)$
for all $x\in I:=\left[0,1\right]$. By swapping $f,g$, we can assume
$f\left(0\right)<g\left(0\right)$. If we had $f\left(x\right)\geq g\left(x\right)$
for some $x\in I$, the intermediate value theorem (applied to $f-g$)
would yield the claim, in contradiction to our assumption. Hence,
$f\left(x\right)<g\left(x\right)$ for all $x\in I$.

By continuity, there is $\varepsilon>0$ with $\varepsilon+f\left(x\right)\leq g\left(x\right)$
for all $x\in I$. In particular $g\left(x\right)\geq\varepsilon$
for all $x\in I$.

By induction, we show $g^{n}\left(I\right)\subset\left[n\varepsilon,\infty\right)$
for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$. For $n=1$, we just showed that this holds.

Now, assume $g^{n}\left(I\right)\subset\left[n\varepsilon,\infty\right)$
and let $x\in I$ be arbitrary. We have
\begin{eqnarray*}
g^{n+1}\left(x\right) & = & g\left(g^{n}\left(x\right)\right)\\
 & \geq & \varepsilon+f\left(g^{n}\left(x\right)\right)\\
 & \overset{f\circ g=g\circ f}{=} & \varepsilon+g^{n}\left(f\left(x\right)\right)\\
 & \overset{\text{induction}}{\geq} & \varepsilon+n\varepsilon\\
 & = & \left(n+1\right)\varepsilon
\end{eqnarray*}
and thus $g^{n+1}(I) \subset [(n+1)\varepsilon, \infty)$.

For $n$ large enough, this is a contradiction to $g\left(I\right)\subset I$.
Hence, the claim must hold.

Comment: +1, I'm curious: how much time did it take you to figure this out? I knew that on the assumption $g > f$ we will reach some place where $g$ is forced to jump above $1$, but I couldn't formulate a good proof. Though, I don't think that the step: "$\exists \ \epsilon > 0, \epsilon + f(x) \le g(x)$" requires continuity, or am I missing something? The negation "$\exists \ x \in I, \ \forall \epsilon > 0, \epsilon + f(x) > g(x)$" proves false as $\epsilon \to 0$, which doesn't need continuity.

Comment: @BolzWeir: The point where I am using continuity is that $g-f$ assumes its (positive) minimum on the compact interval $[0,1]$. I think the point you are missing is that we want $\exists \epsilon \forall x:\epsilon+f(x)\leq g( x)$, the negation of which is $\forall\epsilon \exists x: \dots$, not $\exists x\forall \epsilon:\dots$. Oh and it took me some time, but less than an hour (I think). As is often the case, I can't say exactly how I got that idea. I was just fiddling around and suddenly **bam** :)

Answer (score 1):

I haven't worked through it all, but I would start by assuming wlog that $f(0) < g(0)$, then use the composition reversal to show that $f < g$ cannot hold everywhere. Then the result will follow from the intermediate value theorem.

Comment: ... and how exactly are you going to show that?

Comment: @RobertIsrael: One possibility is outlined in my answer :)